# Is this a quadractic function?

Tags: quadratics

A quadratic function can assume this form:

$$ q(x) = x^{T}Gx + x^{T}c $$

Taking that into consideration is this a quadratic function?

$$ 2{x_{1}}^2 + 3x_{1}{x_{2}}^2 + 6{x_{1}^{2}}x_{2} + {x_{2}}^2 + 4x_{1}x_{2} + x_{2}$$

Having ${x_{2}}^2$ and multiplying that by $x_{1}$ makes me unsure

Comment: Do you know what the "(total) degree" (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/408491/96384) of a polynomial is? Do you see what the total degree of a $q(x)$ should be?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg According to that the total degree of that function is 3, so it is not a quadractic function